# Check if value in source flat file exists in target table with Informatica

Tags: mapping, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping that filters out a number of IDs from source flat file and then inserts it into target table. I want to add a condition to check whether the ID exists in target table, and if the ID doesn't exist, the row should be added to error file. How can I get this done? I know we can use a dynamic lookup but that will only insert or update into target table, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a normal lookup on the target. If the return value is null, then route it to the error file using a router.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write the unmatched rows to error file, use DD_REJECT in update strategy trans based on output from lookup

eg: IIF (NOT ISNULL(col_1), DD_REJECT, DD_INSERT)

col_1 is output from LKP